# Gmail Email Client and SPF Records

Tags: gmail, cpanel, spf

I am in the process of migrating our staff's email client from Window's Live Mail to Gmail. I have gone through the process of connecting each staff's email from our domain to their respective Gmail accounts (so each staff has two valid email addresses, e.g. bob.our_domain@gmail.com and bob@our_domain.com). I am able to receive and send mail from the linked account, but emails sent from bob@our_domain.com are tagged with an alarming red question mark and read "Gmail could not verify that our_domain.com actually sent this message (and not a spammer) ". I understand that this is an error with SPF configuration but for the life of me cannot figure out what the correct configuration looks like.

The domain in questions is evergreensupplyonline.com.

Step 1 - Ensure SPF is enabled. 
Our server is managed through cPanel, so I navigate to the authentication tab and enable both DKIM and SPF. The default SPF record is

```
v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:166.62.38.87 ~all
```

Sending email with this configuration generates the error: `SOFTFAIL with IP 208.109.80.60`. Seems reasonable enough, the IP isn't listed and the `~all` specifies a soft fail for unknown IPs (as far as I am aware)

Step 2 - Add the sender's IP to the SPF record

I add 208.109.80.60 to the record and my SPF record becomes

```
v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:166.62.38.87 +ip4:208.109.80.60 ~all
```

Sending email with this configuration still generates a SOFTFAIL error but with a different IP (208.109.80.60). Based on this change I assume I won't be able to add a static IP for all of google's mail servers - not too much of a surprise.

Step 3 - Add Google's _spf domain
Following the instructions from https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en

I removed 208.109.80.60 and instead include `_spf.google.com` domain. My SPF record now looks like

```
v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:166.62.38.87 +include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

If I run my domain through https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/ I get some some non-critical errors but everything relating to the `_spf.google.com` domain seems to check out. If I send an email with this configuration I still get a SOFTFAIL error.

I'm not sure where to go from here - I've tried all that my preliminary understanding of SPF will permit. Any suggestions, observations, or tricks are greatly welcomed. Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does all look correct, apart from one thing. I looked up both the IPs you mentioned (using `whois`) and they belong to... GoDaddy, not Google, which entirely explains your problem. It's quite likely that GoDaddy is redirecting your outbound email traffic since they don't allow direct SMTP sending, so you may need to add GoDaddy's SPF as well, or move to a more enlightened hosting provider.

A minor thing: put the `ip4` mechanism first as it's fastest to match for receivers (it requires no extra lookups), and you don't need the `+` qualifiers because that's the default action.

Comment: Thank you for that observation, I had assumed (incorrectly!) that the 208.109.80.x IPs were from Google. I'm not entirely clear on how GoDaddy gets involved in the mix, the domain is registered through TuCows/Hover? Either way, I'll try adding GoDaddy's SPF domains and see if I can make some progress there.

Comment: I suppose it's actually pretty simple -  the _domain_ is registered through TuCows but GoDaddy is providing the _server_ and access to server management through cPanel. Thank you again for your help.